# What brand are these pex threaded T connectors?

Tags: pex, connectors

Has anyone ever seen these type of PEX connections?  I can't find them anywhere online or otherwise.

[image]

Comment: “Like these?”  Do you mean you can’t find a T-connector?  Or one that looks identical? Or one that connects the same way?  Your question lacks detail of what issue you a really having.

Comment: I think the OP means can anyone give the mfgr and model of these connectors?

Comment: Yes identical to these.  Just by the looks I would say these are some type of flare.  Does not appear to have any crimping involved.  I was close to taking one apart but just couldn't find it in myself to disturb it.  I have worked with PEX in the past and saw many connectors except this one.  Very curious on the mechanics behind it.

Answer (score 6):

These are actualy "Qest" (pronounced "quest") brand fittings that were more popular 10-15 years ago (maybe further back).  I remember in the early 2000's these were sold at Home Depot and Lowes back before they had very much PEX plumbing supplies.  They were common in mobile homes.

Here is a sample at a plumbing supply retailer:

https://www.ferguson.com/product/qest-plastic-compression-tee-assembly-qqat/_/A-ProdFamily-216224

Comment: These are apparently manufactured by ZURN.

An alternate source : https://www.amazon.com/TEE-QEST-CTS-MfrPartNo-QAT444R/dp/B000H5OPUO/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1520929822&sr=8-1&keywords=QEST

Comment: Well I'll be darn,  kinda tough to find but that's them for sure. Yes they are all thoughout a mobile home, seems to be very poor attempt at a re route.  None appear to be leaking but the pump pressure drops a few psi thoughout the night.  Do you think these should be changed out to crimp or just leave as is?  Thanks.

Comment: @vin944, I'd say if they are not leaking there's no reason to change them.  They are full-port connectors - they do not internally reduce in size or restrict flow.  It was my experience that most people buying the fittings were fixing freeze damage or some other mechanical damage rather than the fitting "wearing out" or something.  The plastic in the picture looks good and shiny.

Comment: You know I was just thinking the same thing.  The ID of brass crimp connectors is really a limiting factor which in turn I'm sure reduces the flow.  And I can tell you that the cuts from the previous pex were made from under the mobile home and the reroute is almost completely inside now.  So they probably froze.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is a PEX plastic flare compression fitting.

Not an endorsement just a link: [Plastic PEX Compression Flare Fitting](https://www.completemobilehomesupply.com/Half_by_Three_Quarters_Female_Adapter_p/flairit154.htm)

[image: Flair Compression PEX Fitting]

Comment: That is the oddest thing.  How is that connector holding 60+ psi of water?  Even the tightest crimp I have done in the past leaked.  Not all of them but a couple.  Is there a compression ring that goes around the PEX, kinda like copper for a toilet?  Thanks.

Comment: @Vin944  When you push that PEX tube the inner ringer is forcing it outwards and the outer ring which goes around it is pressing the outside tightly and gets compressed down onto the PEX tube. Depending on how your crimp is done and what tool you use to crimp with you can have leaks or cut the tube with your crimp; this is why compression fittings are so well received - they have a perfect closure angle (circle) and leave no room for a crimp error. Compression fittings that are not installed properly can fail but you have to work at it to accomplish a failed installation.

Comment: @vin944 not enough space in earlier comment .. think about push to fit connections.. they do the same thing and are really compression fittings they just have a jaw system to clamp the hose and keep it from being pushed back out.

Comment: So this is just a Sharkbite type fitting?  I've definitely used Sharkbite/Gatorbite before but for some reason this did not appear to look like that.  Thanks.

Comment: @vin944  Sharkbite is a brand. However the compression type and push fittings are all very similar types - and many manufacturers make them differently. I am thinking yours probably has or had some marking on it somewhere to indicate manufacturer.

Comment: Regarding my edit: *Flair-It* is a brand of *flare* fitting. ([Flare](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flare) is the widening or expansion of a shape. [Flair](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJtrLKGZZFg) is what a plumber wears on his nifty vest to express his unique character and sunny disposition.)